# Python Tkinter: create a list with Entry, and send the list updated to another class

Tags: python, tkinter

My target is to make a GUI program, using Tkinter, that makes a window with one button, which opens another window in which there are two lables, that represent the coordinates x and y of some points that the user has to write. This coordinates must be inserted in a list (for exaple: [[0,1],[2,3],...). Then, I just want to draw these points in the canvas, whit the function create_oval.
This is my code

```html
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox, tkFileDialog


class nodes(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, relief=SUNKEN, bd=2)    
        
        self.root_nodes = Tk()
        self.root_nodes.geometry("200x150")
        
        self.lista=[]        
        Label(self.root_nodes, text="x: ").pack()
        self.x = Entry(self.root_nodes)
        self.x.pack()
        Label(self.root_nodes, text="y: ").pack()
        self.y = Entry(self.root_nodes)
        self.y.pack()
        self.ok = Button(self.root_nodes, text="OK", command=self.OK)
        Label(self.root_nodes, text="\n")
        self.ok.pack()
        self.fine = Button(self.root_nodes, text="END", command=self.end)
        self.fine.pack()
        
    def OK(self):     
        self.lista.append([float(self.x.get()),float(self.y.get())])
        
    def end(self):       
        return self.lista        
        self.root_nodes.destroy()



class AppUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, relief=SUNKEN, bd=2)
        
        def points():
            x = nodes()
            self.a = x.end()
            print self.a

        #here
       
        self.frame = Frame(root)
        self.point = Button(self.frame, text = "Points", command = points).pack()
        self.frame.pack(side =LEFT, fill =BOTH)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self, bg="white", width=400, height=400,bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
        #for i in range (0, len(self.a)):
            #self.canvas.create_oval(self.a[i][0] - 1 , self.a[i][1] - 1, self.a[i][0] + 1 , self.a[i][1] + 1)
        
        self.canvas.pack()
  
        try:
            self.master.config(menu=self.barra_menu)
        except AttributeError:
            # master is a toplevel window (Python 1.4/Tkinter 1.63)
            self.master.tk.call(master, "config", "-menu")


root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

miaApp = AppUI(root)
miaApp.pack()
root.mainloop()

#here
```

I have some questions:

1. First of all: is this an elegant way to create and initialize windows with the classes? Because I saw many way to do that
2. Obviously, when I print self.a in the AppUI, it prints an empty list, because in the previous class I initialized self.lista=[]! 
   So I need something that updates the variable self.lista, so that it can arrive whith all the points at AppUI
3. Why if I click the button END in the root_nodes it doesn't destroy?
4. Last thing: classes must "communicate", because I want my variable lista in many "places" of the code: of course in the class AppUI, where I put the canvas (the first #here), but also in the main body of the code (the second #here), because I must do some operation with it

Thank you so much

Comment: "Why if I click the button END in the root_nodes it doesn't destroy?" --> because the return is before the destroy so the destroy is never executed.

Answer (score 0):

> My target is to make a GUI program, using Tkinter, that makes a window with one button

```
from Tkinter import *

class OneButton():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master=master
        Button(master, text="Get Coordinates", command=self.get_coords).grid(row=0)
        Button(master, text="Exit", command=master.quit).grid(row=1)

    def get_coords(self):
        self.N=Nodes(self.master)
```

> which opens another window in which there are two lables, that represent the coordinates x and y of some points that the user has to write.

```
class Nodes():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.root_nodes = Toplevel(master)
        self.root_nodes.geometry("200x150")

        self.lista=[]        
        Label(self.root_nodes, text="x: ").grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.x = Entry(self.root_nodes)
        self.x.grid(row=0, column=1)
        Label(self.root_nodes, text="y: ").grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.y = Entry(self.root_nodes)
        self.y.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.ok = Button(self.root_nodes, text="OK", command=self.OK)
##        Label(self.root_nodes, text="\n")
        self.ok.grid(row=5, column=0, columnspan=2)
        self.fine = Button(self.root_nodes, text="Close this window", command=self.end)
        self.fine.grid(row=10, columnspan=2)

    def OK(self):     
        self.lista.append([float(self.x.get()),float(self.y.get())])
        print self.lista

    def end(self):       
        self.root_nodes.destroy()
```

> Then, I just want to draw these points in the canvas, whit the function create_oval

```
class AppUI():
    def __init__(self, master, lista):
        self.master=master

        self.frame = Toplevel(master)
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.frame, bg="white", width=400, height=400,bd=0,
                              highlightthickness=0)
        self.canvas.grid()
        for x, y in lista:
            print x, y
            self.canvas.create_oval(x, y, x+10, y+10, fill="black")

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")

miaApp = OneButton(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: sorry but it does'nt works. The canvas does not appear!

Comment: You have to create an instance(s) of AppUi from somewhere in the programs.  I do not know when or where you want to do that.  The code was meant as an example of how it is done taking points from a list passed to the class, as you did not have the code to do this in your post.